# How to retrive an item ID from Sharepoint when user clicks on the item in the List?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I have a SharePoint list that has many items in it. How can I find out which item the user clicked on? I need to pass that value to getItemByID() so that I can access the data within the form. I am also trying to do this in the Page_load method.

Comment: you mean out of box list or do you have any custom page for list items display?

Comment: It is a hybrid solution. The page is OOB, the view is OOB but the form is custom.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getSelectedItems`

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);

            if (items.length > 0) {
                var itemids = [];
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    itemids.push(items[i].id);
                }
```